# Xamarin.Forms: Override hight of 6th row of grid from code

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have this grid:

```
            <!--MainGrid-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="maingrid_piccat">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ImageButton
                         Aspect="AspectFit"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Source="btn_emptydummy.png" BackgroundColor="#00000000"/>

                    <Picker x:Name="picker_maincat_pickcate" 
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Title="Hauptkategorie"
                            FontFamily="arial"
                            BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                            TextColor="#272727"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                            VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Picker.Items>
                            <x:String>Cat 1</x:String>
                            <x:String>Cat 2</x:String>
                            <x:String>Cat 3</x:String>
                            <x:String>Cat 4</x:String>
                        </Picker.Items>
                        </Picker>

                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ImageButton
                         Aspect="AspectFit"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Source="btn_emptydummy.png" BackgroundColor="#00000000"/>

                    <Picker x:Name="picker_subcat1_pickcate" 
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Title="Unterkategorie 01"
                            FontFamily="arial"
                            BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                            TextColor="#272727"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                            VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Picker.Items>
                            <x:String>Subcat yx</x:String>
                            <x:String>Subcat yx</x:String>
                            <x:String>Subcat yx</x:String>
                            <x:String>Subcat yx</x:String>
                        </Picker.Items>
                    </Picker>

                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ImageButton
                         Aspect="AspectFit"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Source="btn_emptydummy.png" BackgroundColor="#00000000"/>

                    <Picker x:Name="picker_subcat2_pickcate" 
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            FontFamily="arial"
                            Title="Unterkategorie 02"
                            BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                            TextColor="#272727"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                            VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Picker.Items>
                            <x:String>Subcat yx</x:String>
                            <x:String>Subcat yx</x:String>
                            <x:String>Subcat yx</x:String>
                            <x:String>Subcat yx</x:String>
                        </Picker.Items>
                    </Picker>

                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ImageButton
                         Aspect="AspectFit"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Source="btn_emptydummy.png" BackgroundColor="#00000000"/>

                    <Picker x:Name="picker_subcat3_pickcate" 
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            FontFamily="arial"
                            BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                            TextColor="#272727"
                            Title="Unterkategorie 03"                                
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                            VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Picker.Items>
                            <x:String>Subcat yx</x:String>
                            <x:String>Subcat yx</x:String>
                            <x:String>Subcat yx</x:String>
                            <x:String>Subcat yx</x:String>
                        </Picker.Items>
                    </Picker>

                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="4" x:Name="row4_piccat">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ImageButton
                        x:Name="btn_dummy_piccat"
                         Aspect="AspectFit"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Source="btn_emptydummy.png" BackgroundColor="#00000000"/>

                    <Entry x:Name="entry_name_pickcat" 
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            FontFamily="arial"
                           MaxLength="15"
                           Placeholder="Titel der Anzeige" 
                            BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                            TextColor="#272727"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                            VerticalOptions="Center">
                    </Entry>

                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="5" x:Name="row5_piccat">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ImageButton
                         Aspect="AspectFit"
                         x:Name="btn_dummy_piccat2"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Source="btn_emptydummy.png" BackgroundColor="#00000000"/>

                    <Entry x:Name="entry_descri_pickcate" 
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            FontFamily="arial"
                           MaxLength="50"
                           Placeholder="Kurzbeschreibung" 
                            BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                            TextColor="#272727"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                            VerticalOptions="Center">
                    </Entry>

                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="6">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ImageButton
                        Margin="10,10,10,10"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Aspect="AspectFit"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                x:Name="name_btnfoto_pickcat"
                BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                Source="fotobutton.png" />



                </Grid>

            </Grid>

        </Grid>
```

But I wanna override the last to rows content. Just a little text that shows up in row 5:

```
private void SetLayoutForTakers()
{
    btn_dummy_piccat2.IsVisible = false;
    entry_descri_pickcate.IsVisible = false;



    Grid grid = new Grid(); //Neues Grid
    BoxView bx = new BoxView();
    Label lb = new Label();


    //Label Properties
    lb.Text = "Tipp: Sie können auch nur nach Titeln suchen, oder nach bestimmten Titeln in einer oder mehrerer Kategorien!";
    lb.TextColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.White;
    lb.FontSize = 12;
    lb.FontFamily = "arial";

    bx.Color = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Red;

    grid.Children.Add(bx);
    grid.Children.Add(lb);

    RowDefinitionCollection rdc = new RowDefinitionCollection();
    rdc.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
    maingrid_piccat.RowDefinitions = rdc;

    row5_piccat.Children.Add(grid,1,1);

}
```

As yopu can see, I tried altering the row defitions, but it doesnt seem to affect the grid. 
Here is the result:[image]

As you can see, the text is cut off, because the gridrow is too small.
How can I just alter its height in the code that it displayes the whole string?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Grid.RowSpan` and set It to 2 where the Text resides. What it does it makes the RowSpan to the number provided and makes the VisualElement span from the Starting Row provided in `Grid.Row` and going to the number of Row provided in `Grid.RowSpan`.

Let me know in case you have further queries.

Update:-
Xaml

```
Grid.RowSpan="{Binding IsTwoRowVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToIntRowSpanConverter}}"
```

Converter:-

```
public class BoolToIntRowSpanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return "";
            else if ((bool)value)
                return 2;
            else return 1;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

So whenever that the bool is set to true or false the Row.Span will change accordingly.

Comment: Hello, this would work from xaml, but not in code. I need it to be at runtime.

Comment: I had a similar problem earlier, I solved it buy using a Bool and a Converter in ViewModel. Kindly see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create binding on RowDefinition.Height, change the height via viewmodel.

#### Xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Height}"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Red"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Green"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="Blue"></Label>
</Grid>
```

#### Code behind

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private GridLength height;
    public GridLength Height { 
        get {
            return height;
        } 
        set {

            height = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        } }

    public MyModel()
    {
        Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    }
}

[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Page8 : ContentPage
{

    public MyModel model; 

    public Page8()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        model = new MyModel();


        this.BindingContext = model;

    }




    private void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        model.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
    }
}
```

[image]